# Healthy Elasticsearch cluster turns RED after opening a closed index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a managed cluster hosted by elastio.co. Here is the configuration
|`Platform => Amazon Web Services`|   |`Memory => 4 GB`|
|`Storage => 96 GB`|      |`SSD => Yes`|       |`High availability => Yes 2 data centers`|

Each index in this cluster contain log data of exactly one day. Average index size is `15 mb` and average doc count is `15000`. The cluster is not in any way under any kind of pressure (JVM, Indexing & Searching time, Disk Space all are in very comfort zone)

When I opened a previously closed index the cluster is turned RED. Here are some matrices I found querying the elasticsearch.

```
GET /_cluster/allocation/explain
{
  "index": "some_index_name",    # 1 Primary shard , 1 replica shard 
  "shard": 0,
  "primary": true
}
```

Response :

```
"unassigned_info": {
"reason": "ALLOCATION_FAILED"
"failed_allocation_attempts": 3,
"details": "failed recovery, failure RecoveryFailedException[[some_index_name][0]: Recovery failed on {instance-*****}{Hash}{HASH}{IP}{IP}{logical_availability_zone=zone-1, availability_zone=***, region=***}]; nested: IndexShardRecoveryException[failed to fetch index version after copying it over]; nested: IndexShardRecoveryException[shard allocated for local recovery (post api), should exist, but doesn't, current files: []]; nested: IndexNotFoundException[no segments* file found in store(mmapfs(/app/data/nodes/0/indices/MFIFAQO2R_ywstzqrfbY4w/0/index)): files: []]; ",
"last_allocation_status": "no_valid_shard_copy"
}, 
"can_allocate": "no_valid_shard_copy",
"allocate_explanation": "cannot allocate because all found copies of the shard are either stale or corrupt",
"node_allocation_decisions": [
  {
    "node_name": "instance-***",
    "node_decision": "no",
    "store": {
      "in_sync": false,
      "allocation_id": "RANDOM_HASH",
      "store_exception": {
        "type": "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "no segments* file found in SimpleFSDirectory@/app/data/nodes/0/indices/RANDOM_HASH/0/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@346e1b99: files: []"
      }
  }
},
{
  "node_name": "instance-***",
  "node_attributes": {
    "logical_availability_zone": "zone-0",
  },
  "node_decision": "no",
  "store": {
    "found": false
  }
}
```

I've tried rerouting the shards to a node. Even setting data loss flag to true.

```
POST _cluster/reroute
{
  "commands" : [
  {"allocate_stale_primary" : {
  "index" : "some_index_name", "shard" : 0,
  "node" : "instance-***",
  "accept_data_loss" : true
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
"acknowledged": true,
"state": {
"version": 338190,
"state_uuid": "RANDOM_HASH",
"master_node": "RANDOM_HASH",
"blocks": {
  "indices": {
    "restored_**: {
      "4": {
        "description": "index closed",
        "retryable": false,
        "levels": [
          "read",
          "write"
        ]
      }
    },
    "restored_**": {
      "4": {
        "description": "index closed",
        "retryable": false,
        "levels": [
          "read",
          "write"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
"routing_table": {
  "indices": {
    "SOME_INDEX_NAME": {
      "shards": {
        "0": [
          {
            "state": "INITIALIZING",
            "primary": true,
            "relocating_node": null,
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "SOME_INDEX_NAME",
            "recovery_source": {
              "type": "EXISTING_STORE"
            },
            "allocation_id": {
              "id": "HASH"
            },
            "unassigned_info": {
              "reason": "ALLOCATION_FAILED",
              "failed_attempts": 4,
              "delayed": false,
              "details": "same as explanation above ^ ",
              "allocation_status": "no_valid_shard_copy"
            }
          },
          {
            "state": "UNASSIGNED",
            "primary": false,
            "node": null,
            "relocating_node": null,
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "some_index_name",
            "recovery_source": {
              "type": "PEER"
            },
            "unassigned_info": {
              "reason": "INDEX_REOPENED",
              "delayed": false,
              "allocation_status": "no_attempt"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

Any kind of suggestion is welcomed. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 17):

This occurs when the master-node is brought down abruptly.

Here are the steps I took to resolve the same issue, that I had encountered ,

- Step 1: Check the allocation

  - curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v
- Step 2: Check the shard stores

  - curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_shard_stores?pretty
    Look out for "index", "shard" and "node" that has the error that you displayed.
    The ERROR should be --> "no segments* file found in SimpleFSDirectory@/...."
- Step 3: Now reroute that index as shown below

  - curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?master_timeout=5m' -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "commands": [  {  "allocate_empty_primary": { "index": "IndexFromStep2", "shard": ShardFromStep2 , "node": "NodeFromStep2", "accept_data_loss" : true } } ] }'
- Step 4: Repeat Step2 and Step3 until you see this output.

  - curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_shard_stores?pretty'

  {
  "indices" : { }
  }

Your cluster should go green soon.

Comment: Thanks! All other docs wrote `allocate_stale_primary` option for the same command, which didn't help our case. And this did.
I wonder why it wasn't selected as accepted answer.

Comment: thanks, allocate_stale_primary worked for me, and I had to add the content type header, probably a new requirement since this question was first answered `-H'Content-Type: application/json'`